# Wack A Mole With Python Syntax/Punctuation

Tags: python

Alright, so I've been playing with this piece of code for a while. What I want it to do is:

a) if yes, continue to the next part of the program. 
b) if no, return back to the questioniare to re-enter the proper data.
c) if neither, request a y/n answer again.

So right now this is what I have so far. I'm working out of Python 3.4.1, and at this point it is telling me "invalid syntax" on the last variable "answer" after the "else" statement. If I try to adjust this statement then it will go on to tell me that a colon is out of place, that the "elif" is "invalid syntax," and that the first "break" in the "if" statement is "out of the loop" due to indentation. So here's my question: where do I start debugging it since all of it seems to be confused?

```
b = input ('Enter outstanding balance: ')
i = input ('Enter annual interest rate as a decimal: ')
m = input ('Enter monthly minimum payment as a decimal: ')

print ('Your oustanding balance is:  ' + b)
print ('Your annual interest rate in decimal form is: ' + i)
print ('Your monthly minimum payment as a decimal is: ' + m)

answer = input('If this is correct please type: yes or no: ')

if answer == ('no'):
    print('You said no! Darn, let me get those numbers again...')
    break
elif answer == ('yes'):
    print ('Great! Let us continue...')
    continue
else answer != ('yes', 'no'):
    print ('You did not answer correctly! Please try again: ')
    break
```

Any and all answers will be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a condition for an `else` (and in this context, it isn't logically needed anyway). Just do:

```
else:
    print ('You did not answer correctly! Please try again: ')
```

Also, `break` isn't proper syntax for an `if` block, so remove all the `break`s from your code. You're probably thinking of `switch` statements, which Python doesn't support.

Comment: I think this is all inside a loop (which he hasn't showed us), and the `break` and `continue` are for that loop. (If not, it _should_ all be inside a loop, because that's the only way he's going to get that "return back to the questionnaire" part.)

Answer (score 1):

First, your `else` is invalid for at least reasons: if you want to test a condition, you need `elif`; if you want to test whether `answer` is equal to neither of two values you need `not in`, not `!=`; etc. But you really have no reason to test anything here anyway. If you didn't do the `if` or the `elif`, you want to do the `else`.

Second, you're missing a `while True:` to go with those `break` and `continue` statements.

Also, you've got `break` and `continue` backward. A `break` breaks out of a loop, and moves on with the rest of the program; a `continue` continues to the next time through the loop.

So:

```
while True:

    b = input ('Enter outstanding balance: ')
    i = input ('Enter annual interest rate as a decimal: ')
    m = input ('Enter monthly minimum payment as a decimal: ')

    print ('Your oustanding balance is:  ' + b)
    print ('Your annual interest rate in decimal form is: ' + i)
    print ('Your monthly minimum payment as a decimal is: ' + m)

    answer = input('If this is correct please type: yes or no: ')

    if answer == ('no'):
        print('You said no! Darn, let me get those numbers again...')
        continue
    elif answer == ('yes'):
        print ('Great! Let us continue...')
        break
    else:
        print ('You did not answer correctly! Please try again: ')
        continue
```

There's still one problem left: You want the third choice to go back to just ask the last question again, not the whole thing. This means you need a loop inside a loop… and you can only `break` or `continue` one loop at a time. This is one of many reasons it's probably worth refactoring this into smaller functions, so you can just `return` when you're done. For example:

```
def yesno(prompt):
    while True:
        answer = input(prompt)
        if answer == "no":
            return False
        elif answer == "yes":
            return True
        else:
            print('You did not answer correctly! Please try again:')

def questionnaire():
    while True:
        b = input ('Enter outstanding balance: ')
        i = input ('Enter annual interest rate as a decimal: ')
        m = input ('Enter monthly minimum payment as a decimal: ')

        print ('Your oustanding balance is:  ' + b)
        print ('Your annual interest rate in decimal form is: ' + i)
        print ('Your monthly minimum payment as a decimal is: ' + m)

        if yesno('If this is correct please type: yes or no:'):
            print('Great! Let us continue...')
            return b, i, m
        else:
            print('You said no! Darn, let me get those numbers again...')
```

Notice I didn't need `break` or `continue` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike switch statements, if-elif-else statements are mutually exclusive so you don't need to break once you enter the block of code corresponding to that conditional branch. Also, else statements can not take conditions since they mean (if none of the above is true). The behaviour you describe is a loop, where a block of code is repeated until a certain condition is met. Using a flag (a boolean variable) and a while loop, you can run that block of code an arbitrary number of times until any of the conditions in the if-elif-else statements are met, at which point you change the value of the flag, which in turn terminates the loop. Here is an example using your code:

EDIT: I reread your specs and modified the code to make it re-ask for yes/no answer only instead of getting the first three inputs again.

```
move_on= False
while (!move_on):
        b = input ('Enter outstanding balance: ')
        i = input ('Enter annual interest rate as a decimal: ')
        m = input ('Enter monthly minimum payment as a decimal: ')

        print ('Your oustanding balance is:  ' + b)
        print ('Your annual interest rate in decimal form is: ' + i)
        print ('Your monthly minimum payment as a decimal is: ' + m)

        answer = input('If this is correct please type: yes or no: ')

        ask_again= True
        while (ask_again):

                if answer == 'no':
                        print('You said no! Darn, let me get those numbers again...')
                        ask_again= False
                elif answer == 'yes':
                        print ('Great! Let us continue...')
                        ask_again= False
                        move_on=True
                else:
                        print ('You did not answer correctly! Please try again: ')
```

Comment: why not just `while True` ?

Comment: You've added at least one SyntaxError to his code, as well as extra complexity.

Comment: This does not contain any syntax errors on my machine, but this is probably due to a difference in the python version (I am using 3.2.3). I don't think it's a good idea to use an infinite loop with break and continue statements; I prefer the flag approach but that's just my opinion.